# Screen remains on after bringing it to my ear during a call

Tags: iphone

While in a call with the phone at my ear the touch screen stays active instead of going off which I am sure it always used to do.

What is now happening is I keep activating the mute or hold button during calls.

This never happened before.  Any tips?

Comment: does your iphone have a case/screen protector etc. which covers the proximity sensor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either the software isn't seeing the proximity sensor or your hardware needs a repair.

I have had good luck testing the phone immediately after a normal reboot (slide to power off and letting it shut down) Then place the phone flat on the table, press sleep/wake to power it on and once it starts - just call 611 or another free call before starting any apps. Place your whole hand over the top half of the glass and play with the sensor that is near the receiver / front camera to see that the screen goes on and off as designed.

Restoring the phone (and sometimes setting up as new) is needed to reset the software when it fails. Calling or going to an apple store for assistance or repair is the next step once you've decided it's not fixable from simple software.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and it got resolved when I removed the screen protector.

Comment: Same with me, removed the screen protector a started to work again. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the above and nothing seems to help so I will probably be making a trip to the apple store for help.

Comment: This actually is a good solution in many cases. Determining what is software failure or hardware failure sometimes needs experience / training / additional tools.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I have an iPhone 4 and an otter box case. The screen was not turning off when I was on a call. If I covered up the top portion of the phone, it still would not turn off. I then took the phone out of the case; against my ear the screen would turn off as ell as when I covered up the sensor. I then put it in a lifeproof case; it turns off against my ear and with my hand covering the sensor.

My conclusion is that the otter box is somehow covering the sensor (although it has not always done this). I would recommend experimenting with/without a case and other cases.

Answer (score -1):

Was facing the same problem as soon as i put a tempered glass screen on it. Solved the issue after the removal.